# I have combined 3 names into one column in a jQuery Ajax DataTable. Now,if I type the word in this column into the data table search, I can't find it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

This code shows that 3 different data are attached to one column of the data table.

```
var table = $('#all_product_table').DataTable({
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: true,
                        "order": [
                            [0, "asc"]
                        ],                         

                        ajax: {
                            url: "{{ route('inspector.table_add_product') }}",
                            type: "GET",
                            data: {
                                'branch_id': branch_id
                            }
                        },
                        columns: [{
                                data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                                name: 'DT_RowIndex'
                            },
                            
                            {
                                data: 'product_name',
                                render: function(data, type, row) {
                                    return row.type_name + ' ' + row.brand_name + ' ' + row
                                        .model_name;
                                }
                            },
```

Comment: Have you checked this link https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/72921/a-simple-datatable-server-side-search-doesnt-work?

Comment: `serverSide: true` search would request to server for searching specific `[search][value]` so you can handle this through your controller.